# ReletableQuery $request->isUpdateOrUpdateAttachedRequest() return null

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

everyone,
I have a problem with an asset in my project.
I have a BelongsTo relation that I can filter using the relatableQuery method.
However I would like to show different data in case I am in the update.
My code is as follows:

```
   public static function relatableTickets(NovaRequest $request, $query)
{


    if ($request->isUpdateOrUpdateAttachedRequest()) {
        return $query->where('availability', '>', 0);
    }


}
```

what happens is that the $request->isUpdateOrUpdateAttachedRequest() method returns a null value, the really strange thing is that doing a
var_dump( $request>isUpdateOrUpdateAttachedRequest())
I get a consistent value other than null, I just can't figure out what the problem is, can someone help me, thanks.

Comment: How do you know it's returning null if you see a value in there when using `var_dump()`?

Comment: I don't know how to explain it but what happens seems absurd, if I do the var_dump I see the value, but if I check that value in the if it does not enter it, when I check in the if the value is null, I know why by checking with "== null" enters the if.

Comment: It seems that the relatableTickets() method is called twice, the first time the $request->isUpdateOrUpdateAttachedRequest() call returns the correct values, in the second invocation it returns a null value, has anyone experienced this behaviour?